# I have a board of cards which i would like to grow on click but remain in the same position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a notice board which has multiple rows of post-it notes. When a note is clicked, it expands providing more details. Currently (while working on mobile view) I have 3 columns of post-its. When i click on the first row of notes they open up and take 100% width of the row they are on. This is the behavior I want. When I open the 2nd or 3rd note it gets pushed down and takes 100% width of the row below. Is there a way i can make it so each note, on click, opens to 100% of the width but remains on the same row?

This is my HTML - i have many more 'posts' but have excluded them as the structure remains the same:

```js
const postIt = document.querySelectorAll(".post");
const active = document.querySelector(".post.active");

postIt.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const expand = item.querySelector('.expand');
    const isActive = item.classList.contains('active');

    if (!isActive) {
      postIt.forEach(post => {
        if (post !== item && post.classList.contains('active')) {
          const otherExpand = post.querySelector('.expand');
          post.classList.remove('active');
          otherExpand.style.display = 'none';
        }
      });
    }

    item.classList.toggle('active');
    expand.style.display = isActive ? 'none' : 'block';
  });
});
```

```css
.postArea{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 5px;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    position: relative;
}

.post{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 20%;
    padding: .5rem;
    margin: .5rem;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 2px;
    transition: width 0.2s ease;
    z-index: 1;
}

.post > img {
    height: 5rem;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.post > p {
    text-align: center;
}

.post:nth-child(1n+1){
    transform: rotate(3deg);
    background: white;
}

.post:nth-child(2n+2){
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
    background: #ffff99;
    width: 25%;
    height: 7rem;
}

.post.active {
    width: 100% !important;
    z-index: 20;
    position: absolute;
}

.expand {
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.pin{
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    margin: .3rem 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px 1px;

}
```

```html
<div class="postArea">
  <div class="post">
    <span class="pin"></span>
    <img src="./Images/bea.png" alt="">
    <p>Forest school</p>
    <div class="expand">
      <p>Today the kids did something else at forst school</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <span class="pin"></span>
    <p>This week at forest school we went for a walk</p>
    <div class="expand">
      <p>Today the kids did something else at forst school</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <span class="pin"></span>
    <img src="./Images/bea.png" alt="">
    <p>Forest school</p>
    <div class="expand">
      <p>Today the kids did something else at forst school</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have being messing around with all different positionings but cannot seem to crack it. I have been wondering if I can use `calc()` somehow but I cannot think of a way and it might not even be possible? I am just not sure.